# How to split a list into smaller lists python

Tags: python

I have a nested list that looks something like:

```
lst = [['ID1', 'A'],['ID1','B'],['ID2','AAA'], ['ID2','DDD']...]
```

Is it possible for me to split the `lst` into small lists by their `ID` so that each small list contained elements with the same `ID`? The results should look something looks like:

```
lst1 = [['ID1', 'A'], ['ID1', 'B']...]
lst2 = [['ID2', 'AAA'], ['ID2', 'DDD']...]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AjayDabas the ids are random strings consist of numbers and characters.

Comment: Add all code to the question, don't post it as a comment!

Comment: _Is it possible for me to split the lst into small lists by their ID so that each small list contained elements with the same ID?_ Yes, it is. Have you actually tried anything?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

grp_lists = []
for i, grp in groupby(lst, key= lambda x: x[0]):
    grp_lists.append(list(grp))


print(grp_lists[0])
[['ID1', 'A'], ['ID1', 'B']]

print(grp_lists[1])
[['ID2', 'AAA'], ['ID2', 'DDD']]
```

Answer (score 0):

using collections.defaultdict:

```
lst = [['ID1', 'A'],['ID1','B'],['ID2','AAA'], ['ID2','DDD']]
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)

for item in lst:
    result[item[0]].append(item)

print(list(result.values()))
```

output:

```
[[['ID1', 'A'], ['ID1', 'B']], [['ID2', 'AAA'], ['ID2', 'DDD']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without external functions: build a set of unique indexes, then loop over the original list building a new list for each of the indexes and filling it with list items that contain that index:

```
lst = [['ID1', 'A'],['ID1','B'],['ID2','AAA'], ['ID2','DDD']]
unique_set = set(elem[0] for elem in lst)
lst2 = [ [elem for elem in lst if elem[0] in every_unique] for every_unique in unique_set]


print (lst2)
```

Result:

```
[[['ID2', 'AAA'], ['ID2', 'DDD']], [['ID1', 'A'], ['ID1', 'B']]]
```

(It is possible to move `unique_set` into the final line, making it a one-liner. But that would make it less clear what happens.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get separate variables like your example of a result:

```
lst1 = [sub_lst for sub_lst in lst if sub_lst[0] == 'ID1']
```

and

```
lst2 = [sub_lst for sub_lst in lst if sub_lst[0] == 'ID2']
```

from that, you can make a function:

```
def create_sub_list(id_str, original_lst):
    return [x for x in original_lst if x[0] == id_str]
```

And call it like that:

```
lst1 = create_sub_list('ID1', lst)
```

If you want a dictionary of the sub-lists, for easier access, you can use:

```
from functools import reduce

def reduce_dict(ret_dict, sub_lst):
    if (sub_lst[0] not in ret_dict):
        ret_dict[sub_lst[0]] = sub_lst[1:]
    else:
        ret_dict[sub_lst[0]] += sub_lst[1:]
    return ret_dict

grouped_dict = reduce(reduce_dict, lst, dict())
```

(If you know that in your list there will only be 1 string after each ID slot you can change both the `sub_lst[1:]`'s to `sub_lst[1]`)

And then to access the elements if the dictionary you use the ID strings:

```
print(grouped_dict['ID1'])
```

This will print:

```
['A', 'B']
```